# Published .Net Core website not working with Systemd

Tags: 18.04, server, systemd, services, nginx

I'm deploying a ASP .Net core app to my webserver. When I run the systemd service it binds to port 5000 and I get a nginx 502 error. When I run the service manually using "dotnet Activecalls.dll" it binds to port 5001 for https which is what I want and the website works correctly. Here is the systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Active Calls Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/ActiveCalls
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/ActiveCalls/ActiveCalls.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=Activecalls-service
User=user
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any idea why it may not work? I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: it's Ubuntu 18.04